# Continuous Integration with Grails

Tags: grails, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, tomcat6

What tool would you recommend for continuous integration in a Grails + Tomcat (+ Ubuntu) environment? Jenkins? Hudson? Something else? I'm not looking for anything complex... simple would do just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just configured a grails job in Jenkins (running on debian). I cannot really say something about other CI servers.. I also know apache continuum but didn't use it for years.

For Debian/Ubuntu you can simply add

```
deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/
```

in your /etc/apt/sources.list and then install jenkins via
apt-get update && apt-get install jenkins

A user jenkins is created.

You might want to change the default configuration in
/etc/default/jenkins
for using another prefix (i.e. set it to jenkins so url will be something like http://localhost:port/jenkins) port or JENKINS_HOME.

Per default jenkins home is /var/lib/jenkins.

You can start/stop/restart jenkins via init.d script (i.e. /etc/init.d/jenkins restart).

Inside jenkins you can then install the "Jenkins Grails Plugin" and add a new "free-style software project" and then inside its configuration (section build) do "Add build step->Build with Grails".

Then for "targets" you can enter something like "clean test-app -unit" (add goals as it fits).

For "Publishing Junit result reports" use a path like YOUR_PROJECT/target/test-reports/TESTS-TestSuites.xml

Also don't forget to install the "Chuck Norris Plugins" for Jenkins... it's the most important plugin ever!

If you also want to use apache2+Jenkins include something like this in your apache site configuration:

```
Include /etc/jenkins/apache2.conf
```

And create the file /etc/jenkins/apache2.conf with the following content:

```
ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://example.org/jenkins
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /jenkins /jenkins
<Proxy http://localhost:8080/jenkins*>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

You have to activate the proxy module:

```
a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

and then restart apache2:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the thorough response. I'll mark it as the solution as soon as I get a chance to try it out.

Answer (score -4):

[Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview) is the best. And I've worked with most of the CIs.