# Build and Deploy Grails App on Jenkins

Tags: maven, grails, jenkins

I've inherited an existing Grails Maven app and have been tasked with looking into automating the build and deployment of it.

It currently uses grails 1.3.7 but will be upgraded to 2.1 soon.

So
1: Is there a way to allow someone log into jenkins and click a button that will automatically create a build?

2: Is there then a follow up task I could use to allow the user deploy the build to a server I have specified beforehand?

Any links to usefull/relevant articles would be great.....I'm fairly new to both grails and jenkins.

Comment: The answer to both questions is yes.  The scope of these questions is too great for a single answer on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 + 2) Yes. This is pretty much exactly what a Jenkins job does.

Take a look at [Continuous Integration with Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911745/continuous-integration-with-grails) for a quick start, or the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) for a slightly less quick start.